# Getting wrong characters on Sharkoon Skiller Pro keyboard on Mac OS X

Tags: windows, macos, keyboard, layout

I have a new gaming keyboard, called the [Sharkoon Skiller Pro](http://www.sharkoon.com/?q=en/node/2644) and I’m trying to use it with my MacBook Pro (2014). But it seems like all of the different keys are at different places.

For example, I press the <kbd>delete</kbd> key and it shows `#` on the screen. I already tried to change my keyboard layout in the “System Preferences” but nothing worked.

Is there someone out there who knows how to fix this?

Comment: From the page you link: `Supported operating systems: Windows XP/Vista/7/8 (32 and 64 bit)`

Answer (score 3):

According to [this review from “Mark” (April 18, 2013) on Amazon](http://www.amazon.com/gp/review/R36GF8H1UXBULH/ref=cm_cr_pr_rvw_ttl?ie=UTF8&ASIN=B009K7QB8O)  titled, [“If I could go back a year, I wouldn't have purchased (updated)”](http://www.amazon.com/gp/review/R36GF8H1UXBULH/ref=cm_cr_pr_rvw_ttl?ie=UTF8&ASIN=B009K7QB8O) this keyboard won’t ever work correctly on Mac OS X no matter what you do:

> So, for starters, for those looking to buy this keyboard to use with
>   OSX, don't. It's not compatible and there are no drivers or software
>   available from the manufacturer for OSX. There aren't any work
>   around's and OSX won't be able to recognize it if you try to configure
>   it through settings.